# Add "Most starred" filter in chat stars

Tags: feature-request, chat

Stars are nice, but having a "Most starred" filter would be even better: these stars would be timeless.

Everyone I've talked with about this agrees that this feature should exist. There's not much disagreement or drama about it.

Unicorns also agree that this filter should exist.

Comment: 19 seconds and 2 stars, damn, ps i speak for the shreks we want stars we want moar stars !

Comment: My counter argument is that if you give people a way to see the most starred items (and to star them some more) then those items will remain the most starred forever. The barrier to get into that 'most starred' area will be a moving target.

Comment: @Luggage you can't star from the stars list (see http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/17/javascript?tab=stars ), so it's not much of an issue.

Comment: Then I retract my objection.